# Google now on moto 360 thinks i am talking in arabic

Tags: languages, google-now, motorola-moto-360

Everytime I say somehting to my moto 360, it thinks I said something in arabic and searches for something absurd in arabic.

How can I change that? I don't remember ever setting it to arabic

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the **voice language settings** of the Google app on your phone. You select several ones. You just have to tap and hold to select the main one.